# C++ Деструктор для массива char!

Tags: c++, массивы, классы, char

Такой вопрос, мне нужно было написать класс очереди и реализовать его через меню. В условиях есть момент, что массив должен быть типа char и его максимальный размер (5) нужно указать в самом классе. Это я реализовала, единственное, у меня не выходит прописать деструктор для этого класса с массивом char.

Код самого класса:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int maxSize = 5;

class BurtuRinda {
private:
   char queue[maxSize];
   int size = 0;
   int head, tail;
public:
   BurtuRinda();
   ~BurtuRinda();
   void Enqueue(char ch);     
   void Dequeue();            
   void Count();  
   bool IsEmpty();            
   bool IsFull();             
};
```

Код реализации конструкторов, деструкторов и методов.

```
BurtuRinda::BurtuRinda() {
head = tail = -1;
}

BurtuRinda::~BurtuRinda() {
   delete [] queue // вот тут код не работает, ниже скрин ошибки
   size = 0;
}

void BurtuRinda::Enqueue(char ch) {
    if (IsFull()) {
       cout << "Full" << endl;
       return;
  }
   else {
       queue[tail] = ch;
       tail++;
       size++;
   }
   return;
}

void BurtuRinda::Dequeue() {
   char ch;
   if (IsEmpty()) {
       cout << "Empty" << endl;
   }
   else {
       for (int i = 0; i < tail - 1; i++) {
           queue[i] = queue[i + 1];
       }
       tail--;
       size--;
   }
   return;
 }

 void BurtuRinda::Count() {
    cout << size << endl;
 }

bool BurtuRinda::IsEmpty() {
   return (head == tail);
}

bool BurtuRinda::IsFull() {
   return ((tail - maxSize) == head);
}
```

Деструктор не работает :(
Я знаю, что можно прописать массив таким образом char* queue - но как тогда, мне указать максимальный размер массива в самом классе?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не надо удалять то, что не выделяли :) Это не динамически выделенная память, она освободится при удалении объекта без вашего участия, как и выделена без него...

Comment: а, хорошо, поняла, спасибо! просто в основном коде я реализую запрос у пользователя таким образом - 
case 1: if (!ir) {
                    cout << "Create the queue!" << endl;
                    rinda = new BurtuRinda();
                    ir = true;

Comment: Тогда весь обьект находится в куче, и удалять нужно тоже весь обьект. Т.е. в основном коде должно быть `delete rinda;`

Comment: это у меня прописано - case 2: if (ir) {
                    delete rinda;
                    size = 0;
- но потом он все равно выдает ошибку, прикреплю ее к вопросу

Comment: Ну так Вы убрали строку `delete [] queue;` из деструктора?

Comment: То, что создается через `new` уничтожается через `delete`, то что создается через `new[]` удаляется через `delete[]`, все остальное не удаляется вручную. В вашем случае деструктор по умолчанию сделает все как надо.